# Speaking a print string and JSON data from an API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

So i'm working with the speech recognition library in python and i'm making calls to an API. I've created a function called speak that outputs audio from the computer. I wanted to know if its possible to have the speech recognition library to actually speak JSON data that it receives from the API. Here is a sample of my code.

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import requests
import json
import jsonpath
import datetime

url = "APIURL"
key = "APIKEY"

def speak(text, json_response):
    for i in range(0,1):
        tts = gTTS(text= text, lang = 'en')
        file1 = str("hello" + str(i) + ".mp3")
        tts.save(file1)
        playsound.playsound(file1,True)
        os.remove(file1)

def get_audio():
    r =sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ''
        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception" + str(e))

    return said

def print_commands(text):
    if "printer state" in text:
        response = requests.get(url + 'printer' + key)
        # finds specific part of state operational or not
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            speak('state:', json_response['state']['text'])
        elif response.status_code == 409:
            speak("couldn't get any data")

while True:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            text = get_audio()
            print_commands(text)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()
```

As of now it will speak the string that says State but nothing else after that I appreciate any help i can get with this.

Comment: What's happening is that it's treating the json content as a parameter instead of a continuation of the string you want it to pronounce, and you're not using that parameter anywhere in the speak function. Do this: `speak('state: {}'.format(json_response['state']['text']))`.

Comment: you pass the json_response to the speak function but then speak function never uses it so of course it will never say it. Since you have never told your function what to do with the json_response

Comment: Cool it works now thank you both so much!!!!!!